# ArcPy CalculateField_management. NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, arcpy

Why am I getting a `NameError` here?
The basic python:

```
table = r'D:\output.gdb\table'
m = 0.01
arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, 'FIELD_B', '!FIELD_A! * m', 'PYTHON')
```

The error states: `NameError: name 'm' is not defined`
Why is this, as I have just defined `'m'` in the line above?

Comment: You're not passing `m`, you're passing the _string_ "!FIELD_A! * m".  Presumably the error is coming from inside `arcpy.CalculateField_management`, which doesn't know anything about `m`.

Comment: Josh, thanks. So how can the variable 'm' be passed to CalculateField?

Comment: Perhaps pass the string `!FIELD_A! * 0.01` instead?

Comment: This question is likely to have been asked (and answered) many times at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = 0.01
arcpy.CalculateField_management(table, 'FIELD_B', '!FIELD_A! * m', 'PYTHON')
```

You've passed `!FIELD_A! * m` as a parameter to the `CalculateField` tool, and that tool doesn't know what `m` is -- it's an independent function.

If you want to instead treat `m` as a variable, substitute it into the string:

```
'!FIELD_A! * {}'.format(m)
```